# Adjusting size of AMPscript Image() function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We're having to change up a template to pull in images from our Portfolio based on a field in a Data Extension that matches the Portfolio Image External Key, so I'm giving the AMPscript function **Image(1,2)** a shot. It works great for pulling in an image with just the External Key, but I am not seeing any way to alter the size of the image once it has been brought in.

The function actually pulls in the the entire opening and closing *img* tag, so it seems as though we need a way to manipulate this return to add in a height and width tag.

Documentation: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/image2/

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `Image()` AMPscript function, but manipulate it using the `Replace()` function to insert the required height and width. Here's an example (where `email_banner` is the external key of the Portfolio item):

```
%%[
var @img, @displayImg
set @img = Image('email_banner')
set @displayImg = Replace(@img,' src','width="100" height="100" src')
]%%

%%=v(@displayImg)=%%
```

Comment: This is likely the best way to get around the limitations - you could store the width and height part inside the DE as well to help remove the need for manual coding on the email itself.

Comment: Brilliant. Just testing it out and worked perfectly - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a new column to your DataExtension called "ImageURL" (DataType: TEXT) and populate it with the full "**File URL**" (Portfolio -> Image -> Properties) and then use AMPScript to lookup that value:

```
<img src="%%=v(@ImageURL)=%%" Height="100" Width="100"/>
```

Alternatively, you could concatenate your Portfolio Base URL with the ExternalKey ; assuming the image type (JPG/PNG) is always the same:

```
<img src="%%=v(Concat(@YourPortfolioBaseURL,@YourImageKey,'.jpg'))=%%" height="100" width="100">
```