# Can't get the image to show up, since the base URL changed.

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Currently uploading images in SFMC to Portfolio.  I'm searching specifically for this directory in the templates and generate images based from specific name.  However, it looks like the directory has changed.

I was given the solution to use either ContentImageID() or ContentImageKey() - 
However that wont solve the issue in matching the image to the name as I did before.

Comment: Sounds a bit similar to a problem I ran into: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154787/adjusting-size-of-ampscript-image-function  Summary: The Image() function with AMPscript was able to be used to pull in portfolio images regardless of the base URL.

Comment: @AnonWonderer Yeah I used that and it worked. However I'm using a template that generates that image for different emails. I'm trying to find a ways to set it up to pull the right image based on the email.  Sort of like match the image key value to an id. Sort of like, pull image that has the same name as this.

Answer (score 3):

Portfolio directories will automatically change based on various criteria around the number of objects, size, etc. You will not be able to reliably reference a single path for all your assets. An option may be to use the [GetPortfolioItem](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/getportfolioitem5/#GetPortfolioItem) AMPscript function. You can then reference any Portfolio item by its ExternalKey value.

```
GetPortfolioItem("example.gif")
```

Comment: Yeah I used that and it worked. However I'm using a template that generates that image for different emails. I'm trying to find a ways to set it up to pull the right image based on the email. Sort of like match the image key value to an id. Sort of like, pull image that has the same name as this.